# How to Custom Group By multiple records according some criteria

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, c#-4.0, linq-to-sql

please consider this scenario:

I have data like this :

```
 Id          Group            Value
 -----------------------------------
 1            1                100
 2            1                120
 3            1                100
 4            2                90
 5            2                105
 6            3                300
 7            4                123
 8            4                110
 9            5                100
 10           5                110
```

I want to do `GroupBy` on this data as `1,2,3` place in one group and `4,5` place in another group. How I can do this with `LINQ`?

thanks

---

**Edit 1)**

I want to place `1,2,3` in one group and `4,5` in another group and perform `Count` aggregation on them and I get **6** for first group and **4** for secnd group

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this?

```
        int[] groupA = { 1, 2, 3 };
        int[] groupB = { 4, 5 };

        var result = data
            .GroupBy(a => groupA.Contains(a.Group) ? "A" : 
                          groupB.Contains(a.Group) ? "B" : 
                          "N/a")
            .Select(a => new
            {
                KEY = a.Key,
                VALUE = a.Count()
            });
```

Comment: Can you write your code in `LINQ Syntax` please?I mean `from a in ... select ...` thanks

Answer (score 0):

Thus grouping rule is completely unclear and you need only count of items, I think *you don't need grouping at all*.

```
int[] groups = { 1, 2, 3 }; // or { 4, 5 } for other groups
var groupsCount = items.Where(i => groups.Contains(i.Group))
                       .Count();
```

You can put this query into method (assume items is a field)

```
int GetItemsCountInGroups(params int[] groups)
{
    return items.Where(i => groups.Contains(i.Group))
                .Count();
}
```

Usage

```
int count = GetItemsCountInGroups(1, 2, 3); // 6
int anotherCount =  GetItemsCountInGroups(4, 5); // 4
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case you want a function which maps `1,2,3` to `1` lets say and `4,5` to `2` lets say, then `func<int,int> grouper = i => (i -1) / 3` should suit your purpose for this data set.

The linq is then:

```
var result = data.GroupBy( r => (r.Group-1)/3,
                           g => g.Count());
```

Note: If this is going to be done database side you need to be careful as the division operator may not map as you want. I.e. in c# int division returns an int so gives you the integer part of the fraction, while the database may return a Double hence breaking the wanted grouping. In this case you will want something like `r => ((r.Group -1) - (r.Group -1) %3 )/3` instead.